# Subscribing to an SNS topic results in the SNSException 'The security token included in the request is invalid.'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sns

I am trying to subscribe a java application on an `EC2` server to a `SNS topic` using the AWS access credentials of an IAM user. This user has `AmazonSNSFullAccess` as one of its Permission policies. Futhermore i've altered the access policy of the topic to the following:

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "__default_statement_ID",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<account_number>:user/<IAMuserName>"
      },
      "Action": [
        "SNS:GetTopicAttributes",
        "SNS:SetTopicAttributes",
        "SNS:AddPermission",
        "SNS:RemovePermission",
        "SNS:DeleteTopic",
        "SNS:Subscribe",
        "SNS:ListSubscriptionsByTopic",
        "SNS:Publish"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:<Accountnumber>:<topic>"
    }
  ]
}
```

But despite having done all of this I still get this error whenever i try to subscribe programmatically.

```
software.amazon.awssdk.services.sns.model.SnsException: The security token included in the request is invalid. (Service: Sns, Status Code: 403, Request ID:
```

It doesn't matter whether i'm attempting to do this locally from my pc or whether the attempt is made while the application is running from an EC2 server in the same AWS account as the SNS topic.

This is the code that i use to subscribe:

```
    SubscribeResponse response = snsClient.subscribe(getSubscribeRequest(instanceCommunicationTopicARN, "https", "/api/notification/ec2-communications"));

    private SubscribeRequest getSubscribeRequest(String topicARN, String protocol, String endpoint) {
        return SubscribeRequest.builder()
                .topicArn(topicARN)
                .protocol(protocol)
                .endpoint(endpoint)
                .build();
    }
```

Here is the SNSClient configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class AmazonSNSConfig {

    @Value("${spring.application.name}")
    public String awsAccessKey;

    @Value("${jsa.aws.secret_access_key}")
    public String awsSecretKey;

    @Value("${jsa.s3.region}")
    public String awsRegion;

    @Bean
    public SnsClient initializeAmazonSnsClient() {
                return SnsClient.builder()
                        .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(AwsBasicCredentials.create(
                                awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey)))
                        .region(Region.of(awsRegion))
                        .build();
    }
}
```

The IAM user of which i'm using the access and secret key does not have an MFA (Multifactor authentication) device enabled, so the error can't be caused by that.

How can i resolve this error?

EDIT: I attached the `AmazonSNSFullAccess` policy *after* i had already created the access and secret keys for this IAM user. Could this be the problem?

Comment: How are you providing the AWS credentials to the app? If you run it locally on your computer, IAM User credentials would need to be provided in a configuration file (using `aws configure`). If you are running it on an Amazon EC2 instance, credentials are normally provided by attaching an IAM Role to the instance. So are the permissions you mention being attached to an IAM User or an IAM Role? More details, please.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein they are attached to an IAM user. The credentials are provided via the `application.properties` property file that comes with the java application.

Comment: Does that property file contain an entry for `AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN`? Since it is an IAM User, a security token should _not_ be provided.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein no it does not, only an entry for the IAM user `access key` and the `secret key`. These are used to instantiate the `SNSClient`, Please see the last code snippet.

Comment: I recommend that you use those same credentials with the AWS CLI to test whether they are working correctly. Use `aws configure` or `aws configure --profile foo` to store the credentials and then try some an SNS command to see whether it works.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I ran the SNS command `aws sns list-subscriptions` in the aws cli using the same access key and secret key and i got a response. So the problem isn't caused by faulty access keys

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I'm able to access SNS with access keys when i switch to using the v1 SNS SDK. So i think these errors are caused by a bug in the java 2.X version of the SNS SDK. I've made a bug report on github about this. https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/3922